# replace double by single backslash

Tags: r, string, text, str-replace, gsub

I need to find a way to replace "\\" by "\" in a string using R. To be more specific, I have text data that is encoded as follows:

```
text <- c("K\\xc3\\xb6nnen", "S\\xc3\\xbcd")
```

I want to convert this to UTF-8, which would give the following result:

```
c("Können", "Süd")
```

However, the data above has one too many backslashes to convert it, i.e. I need to change the text-vector to:

```
text_correct <- c("K\xc3\xb6nnen", "S\xc3\xbcd")
```

Which would make it very easy to encode the data:

```
library(utf8)
as_utf8(text_correct)
```

I already googled a lot, but could not find a way to replace "\\" by "\" this using gsub or similar commands. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on Windows in R 4.2. The poster indicated that this worked on his Mac as well.

Now if the string had been written with single backslashes it would have worked:

```
c("K\xc3\xb6nnen", "S\xc3\xbcd")
## [1] "Können" "Süd"
```

but to the parser double backslash within a character string is a single backslash so just parse it and convert to character.  No packages are used.

```
text <- c("K\\xc3\\xb6nnen", "S\\xc3\\xbcd")

as.character(str2expression(sprintf('"%s"', text)))
## [1] "Können" "Süd"
```

It can alternately be written as a pipeline.

```
text |>
  sprintf(fmt = '"%s"') |>
  str2expression() |>
  as.character()
```

In R 4.1 to get it to work additionally change the encoding to UTF-8.

```
result <- as.character(str2expression(sprintf('"%s"', text)))
Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite appearances, there *are* no double backslashes in your string. There are *single* backslashes. When you want a single backslash in a string in R, you need to type out two backslashes, as in your example.

This is because in an R string, a single backslash indicates that you are beginning an *escape sequence*. An escape sequence makes it possible to enter characters that would otherwise be difficult to handle. For example, if I want a newline character, my string would be `"\n"`. This is *not* stored internally as a backslash and an "n", but rather as the ASCII character 0x0a, i.e. a newline character. The R parser 'sees' the sequence `\n` and reads it as meaning "I want a newline character here".

The reason for having backslash escapes is that we need a way to differentiate between, say, wanting a newline character and wanting a literal backslash followed by the character 'n'. In the latter case, our R string would be `"\\n"`, and would be stored as two ASCII bytes: one for a backslash and one for a lower case 'n'.

You cannot use `gsub` to replace these double slashes for single slashes, since *there are no double slashes*, and the replacements *don't have **any** slashes*. Although the sequence `\xc3` looks like it has a backslash, it doesn't. It is just your way of telling R that you want the single ASCII character 0xc3 in your string.

Essentially your input string has been 'double escaped', and to convert those `\\xc3` entries to the bytes they are supposed to represent, you need to *unescape* them.

Even then, the encoding is not a bytewise representation of the correct UTF-8 characters, so you need to unescape the string using `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode`, but convert that to native encoding, *then* reinterpret it as UTF-8:

```r
text <- c("K\\xc3\\xb6nnen", "S\\xc3\\xbcd")

text <- enc2native(stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text))
Encoding(text) <- 'UTF-8'
text
#> [1] "Können" "Süd"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. This helps a lot and the results already look much better. However, for me the output looks different. I believe it's because of my local encoding, but still didn't find a way to fix it. This is what my resulting vector looks like:
`#> [1] "KÃ¶nnen" "SÃ¼d"  `

Comment: @FelixErpunkt that's the result I get if I run the line `text <- enc2native(stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text))` without then doing `Encoding(text) <- 'UTF-8'`. What result do you get in your console if you do `text <- enc2native(stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text))` then just type `Encoding(text)` into the console?

Comment: If I enter `text <- enc2native(stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text))` and then `Encoding(text)`, R returns `"UTF-8" "UTF-8"`. If I then type `text`, the result remains `#> [1] "KÃ¶nnen" "SÃ¼d" `

Comment: I think it may have something to do with this, though I'm still trying to figure out how to resolve it: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: @FelixErpunkt I think the fact that your native encoding is UTF8 explains it. When I run `enc2native`, the `Encoding` changes to `"latin1"`, which is how these particular strings have to be interpreted. You could try changing your local with `Sys.setlocale(locale = "English_United States.1252")` and running the code again?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a macbook, which means that I cannot change to `English_United States.1252`. I can only change to `en_US.UTF-8`, which does not change the result :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution proposed by @allan-cameron should work for windows users. For mac users, I did not find a better / less brutal solution than this:

(1) copy the table from https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html
and keep columns "expected" and "actual"

(2) Sort table by number of characters in "Actual", starting with the longest string and save as conversion.csv

(3) run the following code:

```
# Read conversion table:
conversion <- read.csv2("conversion.csv", sep=",")

# Run code suggested above    
text <- c("K\\xc3\\xb6nnen", "S\\xc3\\xbcd")
text <- enc2native(stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(text))
# this gives: "KÁ¶nnen" "SÁ¼d"   

# next, loop over conversion table and manually replace miscodings:
for(i in 1:nrow(conversion)){
  text <- gsub(conversion$actual[i],conversion$expected[i], text)
}
text
# this returns: "Können" "Süd"
```